# multiple target specific gnu make variables?

Tags: gnu-make

How do I set more than one target specific variable?

If I try:

```
x: Y := foo Z := bar
```

I end up with `Y = "foo Z := bar"`.  There must be some syntax which will allow for multiple variables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `GNU make` you specify the target multiple times to accommodate the required number of variable assignments, like as:

```
x: Y := foo
x: Z := bar
x:
  @echo Y=$(Y) -- Z=$(Z)
```